# jQuery load function - invisible images

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Im using `load()` function to check if image is loaded. If is, then I'm using 2 other functions.
Code looks like this:

```
$('#img-1').load(function(){        
     someFunction1();
     loadIcons();       
});
```

`someFunction1()` works fine, but `loadIcons()` has class, which has declared background-image in CSS file and this image is invisible(like it wasn't loaded yet)

loadIcons():

```
function loadIcons(){
        $('#gallery').append('<div class="icon" id="icon-1">');
        $('#icon-1').append('<span></span>');
        $('#icon-1').css({
            'top': parseInt(top),
            'left': parseInt(left)
        });
}
```

These elements (`div`, `span`) are visible in Firebug, but image from `.icon` class is invisible. Any idea how to fix it?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    someFunction1()
    {       
            $('#spinner').remove();
            $('#spinner-transparent').css({
                'opacity' : 0
            });
    }

    function loadIcons()
    {
        //code above
    }


    $('#img-1').one('load', function(){     
          someFunction1();
          loadIcons();       
        }).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

**Note:** spinner is a `<div>` with loading `.gif` inside.

Comment: Any CSS rules applied to `.icon` should immediately appear with the element. My guess is that the CSS selector is incorrect, or being overriden.

Comment: `.load` is not only deprecated, but it doesn't work very well for firing on image loads.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but possibly to a future problem: "Depending on the browser, the load event may not trigger if the image is cached (Firefox and IE)." - http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_load.asp

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Without load() function everything works fine, so it must be problem with that function.

Comment: Saying what @TMP but with a more reliable source, "It (`load event`) doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser; [...] Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache" - http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: And that's why the `load-event` is deprecated on jQuery.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté agreed, but user1409508 if you post more code we could help you find a work around

Comment: I've seen a script that detects when the image has loaded and also checks for cache not too long ago, but can't seem to find it.

Comment: [Found it.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3877027/1331430)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Thanks for link, I tried it but it didn't help to fix issue. I updated my first post, now it's almost full code

Comment: @Adnan Thanks for edit, I have no idea why it was so big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had trouble with $.load and ended up doing something like this instead:

```
var img_load_callback = function () {...};
var img = new Image();
img.onload = img_load_callback; // this must be set before img.src
img.src = 'whatever.jpg';
```